# Android tabs event

Tags: android

I stuck with one problem. actually my screen consists of two tabs. under each tab i have 4-4 activity. i m displaying each activity with the help of activity group in single tab.

Suppose i m in 1st tab which is active. Under this tab i m on 2nd activity(e.g first activity is list activity and second activity gives the result from the first activity)

**I want when i click on 1st tab again it should show me the first activity again without using back button.?**

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem sometime ago... and that happens because people like to emulate the bottom bar of the iPhone. Android apps don't work that way and using Activity Group is always a signal of a poor UI design.

Anyway, this is what I did:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_MORE);
tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( MoreGroupActivity.self != null ) {
            MoreGroupActivity.self.reset();
        }
        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_MORE);
    }
});
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_HOME);
```

The above code is not generic, but will give you an idea of the workaround I found. Let me explain:

- `tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_MORE);` I use this to select a current tab (in my case, the main tab was another tab, so I had to to this and then change back with `tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_HOME);`). I mean, in my case, the only tab with that behavior was the "More" tab.
- `tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setOnClickListener` this allows you to put a listener to the tab. As you may have already noticed, using `OnChangeTabListener` is not an option in this kind of situation.
- `MoreGroupActivity.self` Inside my group activity, I had a static field referencing the group activity it self. This kind of hacks are common while using this crappy approach.
- `tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_ID_MORE);` this reset the tab so that it can change back to your first activity.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the fast reply..Where should i use this code? in the activity group? or in all the nested activites in activity group

Comment: In the TabActivity. By the way... accept some of the questions to your answers, or people won't be willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a new `TabHost.TabSpec` to the `TabHost`

use

`.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

to the respective  `Intent`